# webview is changed when changing device

Tags: cordova, webview

I have two nexus 7 devices. I have created an app using phonegap and when I upload it to the devices, they appear differently. The divs are bigger on one of the devices for some reason. Does anyone have an idea what happening there?

Comment: I think its not really possible

Comment: You have to debug, your question is too broad. Inspect window.navigator.

Comment: Check for different Android version

Comment: i solved it. all I needed to do was to set target-densitydpi=medium-dpi. Before I had target-densitydpi=device-dpi

Comment: answer your own question and accept it by your self, so that it will be helpful for others